# how to make each li of a ul have different margin top

Tags: html, css

I am developing a site http://barrecertification.com/signup-options/.
I want each of the certification seal to have a ladder type approach. I mean first one will have more margin-top than second one than last one. But the problem isthat when i apply margin-top all the elements gets the same margin top even if i had differnent class for each element, How to do this?

This is the image of what it will look

[image]

Please help

Thanks

Comment: you ought to put the problem code into the question, having attempted to reduce it down, hen when you fix it on your site the question still has value

Comment: Well you have to make use of jQuery for this. Take the clue form this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rP-PvFjlnWs&list=PLJEjrTIAKlQJecstDi-oUTf_mxsjZpiS6&index=9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `display:inline-block`. All blocks will be threated inlinedish. If you add `vertical-align:top` to `.package`, all `.package` elements will start from the top and then you can add a different `margin-top` value to each `.package`.

```
.package {
    ...
    vertical-align:top;
}

.pac-1 { margin-top:80px; }
.pac-2 { margin-top:40px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give saperate class for each `li`

```
.platinum{
   margin-top: 10px;
}

.gold{
   margin-top: 20px;
}


.silver{
   margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

HTML

```
<li class="small">There put your content</li> ...

<li class="middle">There put your content 2</li> ...

<li class="high">There put your content 3</li> ...
```

;

CSS

```
.small {
 margin-top: "your value"px;
}

.middle {
 margin-top: "your value"px;
}

.high {
 margin-top: "your value"px;
}
```

;

*Hope that will help you! =)*